# Piping the output of `ls` to a second command: file or strings being passed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I'm concerned that this piped command will not do what I intended:

```
ls ASH* | ls -Art | tail -n 1
```

`ls ASH*` - list files with a file name starting with ASH

`ls -Art | tail -n 1` - of passed files, list only the most recent one

However, in retrospect, I'm concerned that what is being piped from the first command to the second command is not actually a list of files, but rather just a list of text strings (file names), which would not make sense to the subsequent command?

Comment: @KamilCuk so does the second command understand that what is being piped to it is a list of files, from which it can access time stamps and pick out the most recent file in the list?

Comment: The (standard) output of the first `ls` is piped into the (standard) input of the second `ls`. But `ls` doesn't read from _stdin_ (standard input). Thus, effectively, the (standard) output of the first `ls` is discarded.

Comment: piping the output of `ls` is a bad idea. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425

Comment: obviously a list of files can't be passed because bash doesn't work with objects. If you want to do that use powershell instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is being piped from the first command to the second command is not actually a list of files, but rather just a list of text strings

Everything is bytes. Let's say, bytes that consist of only printable characters are usually called "text". A list of newline separated file *names* and a list of newline separated text strings, both are just text. It's only text everywhere.

> which would not make sense to the subsequent command?

It doesn't make sense to pipe to `ls`, because `ls` doesn't read standard input. It is irrelevant of what is being piped to standard input.

> does the second command understand that what is being piped to it is a list of files, from which it can access time stamps and pick out the most recent file in the list?

No.